# Angular 2 with Nginx gives 404 Error

Tags: angular, nginx

I am a newbie in angular2 and I have this application that I want to deploy using the dist folder from ng build unto an ubuntu server with nginx installed.

However, when I navigate to my url example.com it works but example.com/dashboard gives me 404 error. I have changed my nginx default file but still I am not getting the result I need.

Below is my nginx default file

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /home/www/example.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your app served correctly locally on the same url?

Comment: @Vega I use ng serve locally so url is the default localhost on port 80

Comment: I meant does localhost:4200/dashboard work ?

Comment: You serve the port 80 in local? strange...

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this information below:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```